# XSL msxsl:node-set problem

Tags: xslt, node-set

Please help me out guys.  I'm just trying to declare a simple result tree fragment and iterate over it.

---

...

```
<xsl:variable name="rtf">
  <item-list>
    <item id="1">one</item>
    <item id="2">two</item>
    <item id="3">three</item>
    <item id="4">four</item>
  </item-list>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)/item-list/item">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

...

---

Am I completely mistaken about how this works?

---

**Edit:** 
I'm using .NET XslCompiledTransform and have the correct msxsl namespace declarations - xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"

The transformating executes fine - the problem is that nothing is output

Comment: I don't think that thats enough code in and off itself to actually output anything...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but this is a snippet of the entire xslt file.  Everything above and below outputs just fine.  It's merely the rtf and node-set which aren't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suspicion is that you have a default namespace declared in your stylesheet. That would effectively place the <item-list> and <item> elements into a namespace. To select namespace-qualified elements using XPath 1.0, you must always use a prefix in the expression.

So if you have something like this at the top of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://example.com"...>
```

Then you'll need to also add this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:x="http://example.com"...>
```

And then use the "x" prefix in your XPath expression:

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)/x:item-list/x:item">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Let me know if that did the trick. I'm only speculating here.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike MSXSL, `XslCompiledTransform` provides `node-set()` function where it is [supposed to be](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) - in EXSLT Common namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
  ...
  <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($rtf)/item-list/item">
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Pavel Minaev Thanks a lot! I use xslt and python and in my case, it was great solution.

Answer (score 1):

This looks OK to me.

Have you correctly declared the msxsl namespace for the extension functions though? Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
```

I am assuming you are using the Microsoft XSLT processor here

Comment: Yep, using MS technologies and have the correct namespace registered.