# Cannot select element in node-set() result using name, but * finds it

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces, node-set

I have an XSLT 1.0* style sheet which does some pre-processing and creates a result fragment consisting of a list of elements `<x>`, each of which has two children - let's call then `<a>` and `<b>`.

So the generated list looks like:

```
<x><a>A-content</a><b>B-content</b></x>
<x><a>A-content</a><b>B-content</b></x>
...
<x><a>A-content</a><b>B-content</b></x>
```

I then convert this into a node set using node-set() and use apply-templates to convert all the `<x>` elements to the output representation.

So far, so good.

But I have to use a `match="*"` rule on the output template, and although I can get the child elements using `"*[1]"` and `"*[2]"`, I cannot find them using `"a"` and `"b"` - I just get an empty result.

The positional syntax works as a workaround, but it's rather fragile and I would like to change it back to working on the element names. Also, it's not very readable.

I did suspect that it might be a namespace problem (`<x>`, `<a>` and `<b>` are not defined in the original schema for the input or output documents), but as far as I can see there is no namespace decoration when the elements are selected using "*".

Just in case it's important, I am using xsltproc under cygwin (libxml 20902, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817).

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or tips on debugging?

(*- *I have to use XSLT 1.0 because it's designed to run in a web browser*.)

---

EDIT: Added examples, as requested

Input test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>

<books>
    <book>
        <title>Diaspora</title>
        <author>Greg Egan</author>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>2001</title>
        <author>Arthur C Clarke</author>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>Eon</title>
        <author>Greg Bear</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

Transform test.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                                xmlns:msxslt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxslt exslt xalan">
<!--    extension-element-prefixes="exslt"> -->

    <xsl:template match="books">
        <!-- Generate list -->
        <xsl:variable name="list">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="book" mode="phase1"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Books</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="function-available('msxslt:node-set')">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxslt:node-set($list)" mode="process-list"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="function-available('exslt:node-set')">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($list)" mode="process-list"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="function-available('xalan:nodeset')">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="xalan:nodeset($list)"  mode="process-list"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$list" mode="process-list"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book" mode="phase1">
        <!-- Actual transformation is more involved -->
        <xsl:element name="x">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="author/text()"/>
                </b>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="b">
                <i>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title/text()"/>
                </i>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="process-list">
        <p>
            [<xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>]
            [<xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>]
            [<xsl:value-of select="a"/>]
            [<xsl:value-of select="b"/>]
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (same output from both msxslt and xsltproc):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Books</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>
            [Greg Egan]
            [Diaspora]
            []
            []
        </p><p>
            [Arthur C Clarke]
            [2001]
            []
            []
        </p><p>
            [Greg Bear]
            [Eon]
            []
            []
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show a **reproducible** example.

Comment: @MathiasMüller What made you decide this is not a namespace issue?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did not decide it was not a namespace issue (apparently, it _is_ a namespace issue), but in my opinion, making prominent the information that a solution needs to be XSLT 1.0 is more important than the namespaces tag. Very few questions where namespaces are the problem are tagged with `xml-namespaces`. Feel free to revert this change if you disagree.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Ah,  I wasn't aware there's a 5-tag limit.

Comment: Re: namespaces. If I remove the "exclude-result-prefixes" element and use copy-of instead of value-of, then the output looks like 

    [<a><b>Greg Bear</b></a>]
    [<b><i>Eon</i></b>]
    []
    []

Comment: ... so no sign of additional namespaces being assigned to the `<a>` and `<b>` elements as far as I can see. If I run this in the XSLT debugger in Visual Studio, I don't see any rogue namespaces either. And yet the named match... doesn't.

Comment: If I explicitly add a namespace using `<xsl:element name="a" namespace="ln">`, then this appears in the output as `<a xmlns="ln"><b xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Greg Bear</b></a>` which is what I would expect, but a match using the namespace explicitly - `"ln:a"` -  still returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have continued searching and found a solution. As we suspected, it was a name-space problem - here's the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859839/xsl-msxslnode-set-problem) describing it.

Despite my attempts to put the new elements in a new namespace, they were still going into the default namespace, which I had declared as:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

This is, however, not treated as a default in the XPATH expression, so it was not found. (Secondary question - why not?)

The solution was to repeat the declaration of the default namespace with a namespace prefix:

```
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

and use that prefix explicitly in the xpath:

```
[<xsl:copy-of select="xhtml:a"/>]
[<xsl:copy-of select="xhtml:b"/>]
```

Then everything matches and I get identical output from the named and position-based XPATH expressions.

Thanks everyone for acting as a sounding board - I hope this helps someone else later.

Comment: Another option is to place created elements into no-namespace explicitly, e.g. `<x xmlns="">` or `<xsl:element name="x" namespace="''">`. -- "*This is, however, not treated as a default in the XPATH expression*" You need XSLT 2.0 for that: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-element

Answer (score -1):

I can only assume, you are using exslt extension to create nodeset, and i guess you are trying to set up a multi-pass conversion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- create your first pass here -->
  <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($first-pass)" mode="second-pass"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- implementation of first-pass
    ....
 -->

<!-- second-pass: find a and b elements in x -->
<xsl:template match="x/a" mode="second-pass">
    <!-- your turn -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x/b" mode="second-pass">
    <!-- your turn -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="second-pass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="second-pass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. My problem is that if I use that construction for the second pass, the templates matching "x/a" and "x/b" never trigger (nor does just "x"). I instead just have a template that matches "*" for the second pass, which picks up all the `<x>` elements because that's all that's in the list at the top level. Within that, `<xsl:copy-of select="*[1]"/>` will copy the `<a>` element, but `<xsl:copy-of select="a"/>` copies nothing.