# Querying results of msxsl:node-set is not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using the `node-set` built-in-function to convert an xsl variable into a nodeset as in the code below

```
<xsl:variable name="allotmentValuesNodeSet" select="msxsl:node-set($allotmentValues)"/>
```

The command `<xsl:copy-of select="$allotmentValuesNodeSet"/>` produces the following output:

```
<values>  
        <month>Mar</month>
        <incomeQTD>1499.63109246680</incomeQTD>
        <realizedQTD />
        <incomeYTD>1519.35773710483</incomeYTD>
        <realizedYTD />
        <incomePrevYTD>1519.35773710483</incomePrevYTD>
        <realizedPrevYTD />

        <month />
        <incomeQTD />
        <realizedQTD />
        <incomeYTD />
        <realizedYTD />
        <incomePrevYTD />
        <realizedPrevYTD />

 </values>
```

When I try to query the node-set variable with this xsl command `<xsl:value-of select="count($allotmentValuesNodeSet/values/month)"/>` I always get `0`, although the result should be `2`.

The `allotmentValues` variable is included between other, outer xml nodes. If I do not include it between any xml nodes, then the code works as expected.

Is there any obvious casue (e.g. namespace related maybe?) for why querying xsl node-sets might break?

If needed, I will try to come up with a simple example to illustrate my problem (I cannot exactly post the code snippet of the issue since it's proprietary code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the variable creation with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="allotmentValues" xmlns="">...</xsl:variable>` and probably the unprefixed path `<xsl:value-of select="count($allotmentValuesNodeSet/values/month)"/>` works.

Comment: This is an elegant fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1859839/1256811) to work in my situation.

Brief description of the issue and solution:

- if the `<xsl:variable/>` from which we derive the node set is included in an xml block with a default namespace, it inherits that namespace
- hence, to correctly carry out XPath queries, one can prefix the nodes with the name of the default namespace, e.g. `count($allotmentValuesNodeSet/inheritedNS:values/inheritedNSmonth)` instead of `count($allotmentValuesNodeSet/values/month)`